Mixed feelings about an LLM response
This post requesting literature about estimation of exponential sums has a reasonable question and an excellent, on-point answer. The answer also looks (to me) extremely likely to have been generated by an LLM. Initially I felt a little outraged, but the reply is actually helpful and has real content. I'm curious what others think Math Overflow's stance should be on things like this.

There have been quite a number of discussions about the use of AI recently. Have you looked through them to see what others think?

A list of titles and authors, without including the references?  Would a mathematician do that?

It's not a good or on-point answer at all.  It's just a random list of papers together with some standard analytic number theory books.

(and I'm sure it's no accident that the first reference is the unpublished PhD thesis of someone who is now an AI researcher)

Well, I notice now that the OP seems perfectly happy with the reply, regardless of source, so perhaps that's answer enough :)

That is not answer enough, given that people can be happy with things that are bad for them <gestures at world politics, also alcoholics found in British pubs>

If we accept things which only superficially copy the semblance of knowledge, we are going to get into problems in the long term when we need reliability or accountability

(Incidentally, has anyone bothered to check if the listed papers actually exist, and if they say what it is claimed they say?)

I am now having a discussion with https://mathoverflow.net/users/539735/laymathematician and the user proposed factoring a linear form into product of 2 linear forms. Sounds to me like an LLM getting confused

@Yemon, I pasted two of the titles into Google (before reading your comment), and got back confirming evidence that those two papers existed, but I stopped short of actually looking at them to see what they did.

Are the conclusions of this discussion at all changed by the poster of the answer stating, "I’d also like to clarify that this is definitely my own writing. In fact, I posted a question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483348/deriving-inequality-8-9-from-8-8-in-iwaniec-kowalski-analytic-number-theor about this topic when I was reading Analytic Number Theory by Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski. I’m deeply interested in this field and happy to share what I’ve learned."?

If AI-generated answers are approved, the policy should state that the author must explain it was AI-generated, say which AI system was used, and give other details like unusual prompts that would be required for someone else to achieve a similar result.
The purpose of a question-and-answer site like Mathoverflow is not just to answer specific questions but to teach people methods and tools they can use to answer their own questions in the future. If they are not already helpful for answering MO-style questions, AI tools might soon be. People who use the tools to answer questions should explain this so other people can learn about the tools and what questions they are successful at answering and what questions they are not. This is similar to pre-existing tools like computer algebra systems: People who use these to answer questions will say which one they used and often give the specific code they inputted.
This would also have a number of other benefits, some just by letting people know what answers are AI-generated and what ones aren't.
In practice this policy would, at the moment, have similar effects to a complete ban on AI-generated answers since most people who post these answers do not say that they are AI-generated, but would have pretty different effects if people start posting AI-generated answers openly.

While this might not be a terrible idea in theory, in practice I think it would lead to a surge of bad AI-generated answers.  The people who are posting them for the most part do not seem to be mathematicians, but tech bros wanting to show off their latest toy.  It's already annoying to have to waste time reading nonsense carefully enough to figure out that it is AI-generated.  I don't think you want to give those people permission to flood the site.

@AndyPutman What I wrote was not clear, so let me add something: My intention was not to say "AI-generated answers should be approved with the restriction that..." but "If AI-generated answers are approved, it should be with the restricted that..."

Thanks for the clarification!  In light of it, I agree with you.

Generally speaking, the OP of a well-posed question should have the lion’s share of say over whether an answer is considered “helpful” or “appropriate” — they’re the one who took the time to formulate and ask the question we’ve agreed is legitimate/interesting.
Incidentally, positions like Yemon’s about knowing what’s best for other people better than they do make me very uncomfortable, along the lines of the old saying:

”Kindly let me help you or you’ll drown”, said the monkey to the fish as he put him up a tree.

We’re all adults who can decide what’s best for ourselves imo, but maybe this is my American cultural conditioning speaking.

As far as my knowledge goes, MO is not intended as an end-user service for getting answers to the questions they could not, or have not bothered to solve otherwise. Its main purpose is collecting high quality answers to questions which are at least somewhat likely to be of interest to mathematicians and students working in similar areas. // While the question is very reasonable, the answer consists of haphazardly collected texts, mostly only glancing on the topic of Kloosterman sums, or being just an application of exp. sum method without providing technical background.

@DenisT Lol, good questions are a big piece of what a PhD advisor provides; I find your position very humorous, but to each their own.

MO is not intended to be a PhD advisor (but maybe I miss your point).

@GerryMyerson Speaking as someone who effectively used it as one, it can be. But if the people here don't want it to be so, c'est la vie; maybe the vision you have for it is better. Personally I find the description given by Denis sterile and unappealing.

@AlecRhea In general, I agree that the OP should have considerable say over whether an answer is helpful or appropriate. However, at the present time, posting an LLM answer without any indication of its origin borders on misinformation. If you ask me a question, and I respond with an intentionally deceptive but cleverly worded answer, should we trust your judgment that my answer was "helpful"? I would say no.

@TimothyChow In my experience, sophist answers are short-lived; they may initially get 'oh gee, thanks!' type responses from question-posers, but upon 'digging in' they find that things don't quite work and come back to query further, usually leading to a revelation of bullshit if any is present. Looking at the response to this answer, it was appreciated by the OP and other experts and the writer is claiming it was human-made (this obviously doesn't prove it, but is worth mentioning I think).

@AlecRhea The particular question under discussion does look to be human-generated, so doesn't fall into the category of "LLM misinformation." But as a general point, the fact that lies are often exposed doesn't morally justify lying.
